# get totals each day based on a given timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```
user   | timestamp
===================
Foo    | 1440358805
Bar    | 1440558805
BarFoo | 1440559805
FooBar | 1440758805
```

I would like to get a view with total number of users each day:

```
date       | total
===================
...
2015-08-23 | 1    //Foo
2015-08-24 | 1    
2015-08-25 | 1    
2015-08-26 | 3    //+Bar +BarFoo
2015-08-27 | 3    
2015-08-28 | 4    //+FooBar
...
```

What I currently have is

```
SELECT From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')        AS date, 
       Count(From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS total
FROM   thetable AS a
GROUP  BY From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER  BY a.timestamp ASC
```

which counts only the user of a certain day:

```
date       | total
===================
2015-08-23 | 1    //Foo
2015-08-26 | 2    //Bar +BarFoo
2015-08-28 | 1    //FooBar
```

I've prepared a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2e6f/1)

**EDIT**

The solution by @splash58 returns this result:

```
date       | @t:=coalesce(total, @t)
==================================
2015-08-23 | 1
2015-08-26 | 3
2015-08-28 | 4
2015-08-21 | 4
2015-08-22 | 4
2015-08-24 | 4
2015-08-25 | 4
2015-08-27 | 4
2015-08-29 | 4
2015-08-30 | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save order of dates, i think, we need to wrap query in one more select

```
select date, @n:=@n + ifnull(total,0) total  
   from 
     (select Calendar.date, total   
          from Calendar 
            left join 
               (select From_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') date, count(*) total 
                    from thetable 
                  group by date) t2 
            on Calendar.date= t2.date
       order by date) t3
     cross join (select @n:=0) n
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dbf9/12)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cumulative values by using variables:

```
SELECT date, total, (@cume := @cume + total) as cume_total
FROM (SELECT From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, Count(*) AS total
      FROM thetable AS a
      GROUP BY From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
     ) a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @cume := 0) params
 ORDER BY date;
```

This gives you the dates that are in your data.  If you want additional dates (where no users start), then one way is a calendar table:

```
SELECT c.date, a.total, (@cume := @cume + coalesce(a.total, 0)) as cume_total
FROM Calendar c JOIN
     (SELECT From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, Count(*) AS total
      FROM thetable AS a
      GROUP BY From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
     ) a
     ON a.date = c.date CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @cume := 0) params
 WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2015-08-23' AND '2015-08-28'
 ORDER BY c.date;
```

You can also put the dates explicitly in the query (using a subquery), if you don't have a calendar table.

Comment: This looks good, but I get a missing field error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2e6f/3 Can you fix the typo so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Can you add the statement for the Calendar table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,`timestamp_field`, CURDATE())
```

You will not have to convert timestamp to other field dypes.

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists thetable;
create table thetable (user text, timestamp int);
insert into thetable values
('Foo', 1440358805),
('Bar', 1440558805),
('BarFoo', 1440559805),
('FooBar', 1440758805);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertTEMP;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE insertTEMP (first date, last date) begin 
drop table if exists Calendar;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Calendar (date date);
WHILE first <= last DO
INSERT INTO Calendar  Values (first);
SET first = first + interval 1 day; 
END WHILE;
END // 
DELIMITER ;

call insertTEMP('2015-08-23', '2015-08-28');

select Calendar.date, @t:=coalesce(total, @t) 
    from Calendar 
         left join 
         (select date, max(total) total 
             from (select From_unixtime(a.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date,
                          @n:=@n+1 AS total
                       from thetable AS a, (select @n:=0) n
                    order by a.timestamp ASC) t1
                    group by date ) t2 
         on Calendar.date= t2.date, 
         (select @t:=0) t
```

result

```
date,       @t:=coalesce(total, @t)
2015-08-23  1
2015-08-24  1
2015-08-25  1
2015-08-26  3
2015-08-27  3
2015-08-28  4
```

Comment: Thanks, can you create a working fiddle on this pls?

Comment: the problem that i can't create procedure on sqlfiddle :( I've update the answer, now you can  copy it in phpadmin to receive the result

Comment: I get `NULL` values on rows without an entry. It should always be the total amount of the certain date

Comment: i take the code here, place it in phpmyadmin, get the result in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. works so far but if I change date from `2015-08-23` to `2015-08-10` I get `4` an dates before the 23rd

Comment: i receive 0 before 23 and 4 till the end of an interval

Comment: The order is wrong and when I use `ORDER BY` the numbers are not correct http://i.imgur.com/4oTtUqf.png

Comment: that's odd, I'Ve copy and paste your code but order is wrong. ok I'll do some further tests, thank you for your help!

Comment: calendar can't be unordered. Left join does not changer order.

Comment: even on a another server same result: http://i.imgur.com/tGjtnx9.png I'm going to find another solution. Thanks!